# Define coordinate system for layers with data from mdb-file (Microsoft Access Database) in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, layers

The point data set from table `points` in the Microsoft Access Database (mdb) file `data.mdb` is visualized as layer `points.lyr` in ArcMap 10.6. The coordinate system is known. However, it is not allocated yet, i.e. the property of `points.lyr` says `Coordinate System: Undefined`. How can I allocate the coordinate system to `points.lyr`? The tool `Data Management Tools` > `Projections and Transformations` > `Define Projection` works for raster files. However, it seems not to work for a layer file with data from a mdb-file.

[image: Screen-shots from processing and error-message]

It is verified that the dataset is neither used by another application, locked nor read-only.

Comment: It is not clear if you are asking about a personal geodatabase (which is an access database) or a traditional access database created in access itself? Please confirm.

Comment: It looks like it is a GDB.

Comment: OK so it's a geodatabase. It is still not clear if your `points` dataset is a featureclass or a simple non-spatial table.

Comment: It looks like it is a featureclass as there is a column called `OBJECTID` and another column called `SHAPE` (`SHAPE` is `Long binary-Data` for all rows).

Comment: So if it is featureclass without a coordinate system then you would typically run the Define Projection tool on that dataset to set it. Which sounds like what you have done. You say it does not work? What is the error message? I would suggest you place that information with a couple of screen shots in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your image you are accessing the geodatabase from within MS Access? That is a real no-no! You can easily (if you have not already done it) corrupt the database.

You must only interact with a personal geodatabase from within ArcMap to ensure data integrity. You create personal geodatabases from within Arcmap, you cannot simply convert an existing access database into a personal geodatabase.

At this point no one knows what you've done and how much damage you have done to it.

So assuming its just that point dataset, I would approached as this:

1. Create a personal geodatabase from ARCMAP
2. In ARCMAP import your corrupted (?) table into your personal geodatabase as a non-spatial table, so you have ID,X,Y, Other fields...
3. Create a temporary XY event layer, at this point set coordinate system.
4. Convert your temporary XY event layer into a FeatureClass by using Copy Features tool.

All this is done inside ArcMap, you never mess around with the geodatabase using Access itself.